# No scrollbars in an overflow: scroll div in Android stock browser

Tags: android, css, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

Is it possible to show scrollbar in a simple div with overflow: scroll in the android stock browser ?

```
<style>
div
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
</style>

<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, it is possible.

Try the following pseudo elements for webkit:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}     

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}     

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.8); 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.4); 
}
```